# How to add a line parallel to y axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a line at `x=c  #constant`.

This should be pretty straightforward, but how can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean like `x=2`, `x=3`, etc. ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.axvline()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.axvline(x=0.2)
plt.axvline(x=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `matplotlib.pyplot`'s `axvline` method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axvline(x=0.5)
```

[image]
You can also set range for the y value:

```
plt.axvline(x=0.5, ymin=0.2, ymax=0.4)
```

[image]
Default value for `ymin = 0` and `ymax = 1`.